# Regex match character not preceded by

Tags: .net, regex

I have a file in which I want to find strings that begin with "abc'", contain the character "s", and end with the word "end". These strings can occupy multiple lines, but in no case contain the word "end" except to mark the end of the string. The regex would look like abc'[^end]*s[^end]* but evidently [^end] isn't going to negate the word "end". I'm using the .NET framework so I have access to lookahead/behind which can negate words, but I've never used them before and I'm not sure how I could solve this problem with them (or if they're needed at all). Any advice?

Comment: I have no idea what to try.

Answer (score 0):

(Revised answer taking into account comments)

One thing regular expressions are very poor at is *not* matching multi-character literals.  That is, it's very good at matching "not x" or "not a space", but it's very difficult (and sometimes impossible) to *not* match a string like "end".  That's why my original attempt at this solution didn't even attempt this.

Given that you could have strings that start with "abc" and end with "end", but *don't* have an "s" in them, you have a bigger problem.  In situations like these, I strongly recommend using two regular expressions: one to match the outer expression, and then one to match the inner exception.  An easy way to use this is to use `Regex.Replace` (even if you don't actually intend to do any replacement), as it allows you to pass in a delegate to do the replacement.  In your case, you could do this:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "abc[\\s\\S]*?end", (m) => {
    if(Regex.IsMatch(m.ToString(), "s")) Console.WriteLine("Found match: " 
        + m.ToString());
    return m.ToString();
});
```

This will not actually do any replacements (as the replacement string is the match itself).  Inside the delegate, you'll be able to examine all strings that start with "abc" and end with "end".  You can simply ignore any that don't have an "s" in them.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, @aelor.  I didn't take into account words that start with `abc` and end with `end` but *don't* include `s`.  Oh well.  Otherwise it was a nice idea.